# How can I properly set the order of divs at different breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap and I want to achieve the following arrangement:

[image: Numbers indicate how they should be ordered in a column on mobile.]

The numbers indicate how I want these divs to be ordered IN A SINGLE COLUMN on mobile. The HTML I tried is here:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="flex-row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="order-1">
            <!-- TITLE SUBTITLE -->
        </div>
        <div class="order-md-3">
            <!-- FILM META AND CONTENT -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="order-md-2">
            <!-- FILM POSTER -->
        </div>
        <div class="order-md-4">
            <!-- UNDER POSTER. -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4? There is no -xs any longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 approaches you can go:

1. Duplicate your HTML elements and show/hide them accordingly
2. Display items as flex columns and set fixed height to make it wrapped
3. Use `column-count`

### Option 1: duplicate elements

The easiest solution would be to duplicate your #2 and #4 onto your left column. On a single column mode on mobile, you show copy of #2 and #4 and hide the right column with `d-none`. On larger screens, you hide the copy of #2 and #4 with `d-md-none` but show the right column with `d-md-block`.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card section-1">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        TITLE SUBTITLE
                    </h6>
                    <p>1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card section-2 d-md-none">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        COPY OF FILM POSTER
                    </h6>
                    <p>COPY OF 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card section-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        FILM META AND CONTENT
                    </h6>
                    <p>3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card section-4 d-md-none">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        COPY OF UNDER POSTER
                    </h6>
                    <p>COPY OF 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 d-none d-md-block">
            <div class="card section-2">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        FILM POSTER
                    </h6>
                    <p>2</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card section-4">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">
                        UNDER POSTER
                    </h6>
                    <p>4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/L2cwf4z3/11/

[image]

[image]

### Option 2: make sure items are displayed as flex-column and utilize the wrapping

You can't use `order` if the items are not in the same row / column. That's why your approach didn't work. But that's what leads to this option #2.

Here I set the container to display as `d-md-flex` and `flex-md-column` on larger screen, and make sure it wraps with `flex-md-wrap`! Since it's displayed as flex column, in order to make it wrapped, we need to set a fixed height on the container.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container d-md-flex flex-md-column flex-md-wrap">
    <div class="card section-1">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">
                TITLE SUBTITLE
            </h6>
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card section-2">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">
                FILM POSTER
            </h6>
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card section-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">
                FILM META AND CONTENT
            </h6>
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card section-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">
                UNDER POSTER
            </h6>
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        height: 40rem;
    }

    .card {
        width: 45%;
    }

    .section-3 {
        order: 2;
    }

    .section-2 {
        order: 3;
    }

    .section-4 {
        order: 4;
    }
}
```

#### DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ypvngd7w/32/

[image]

This option feels like a hack to me though LOL

### Option 3: column-count

You can utilize CSS3 `column-count` feature! I think this is the cleanest approach!

Because with `column-count` you can't change the orders of the items, so you have to pre-arrange the items first. Hence #3 has to come before #2.

On smaller screen, you will have to display them as `flex-column` because you want to use `Order` to arrange the items as 1,2,3,4.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card section-1">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">
                TITLE SUBTITLE
            </h6>
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card section-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">
                FILM META AND CONTENT
            </h6>
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card section-2">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">
                FILM POSTER
            </h6>
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card section-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 class="card-title">
                UNDER POSTER
            </h6>
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.card {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.section-2 {
    height: 20rem;
    order: 2;
}

.section-3 {
    height: 18rem;
    order: 3;
}

.section-4 {
    order:4;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        display: block;
        column-count: 2;
    }

    .card {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

#### DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ve96jx42/9/

[image]

Comment: OMG this looks promising. Thank you so much for your time! I will try these solutions in the morning and report back

Comment: Hey @bogdan: I just added option#3 using mix of flex-box and column-count. Please check that out as well.

Comment: thank you so much for the time you put in, Stackoverflow is an amazing place because of people like you. However I ended up going with Zim's solution for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 1):

The *simplest* solution (**no extra CSS or duplicate markup**) is to use "floats" in Bootstrap 4. Use the `d-md-block` class to "disable" the flexbox on larger screens, and then `float-*` to position the columns. On mobile, the columns will follow their natural order...

```
      <div class="row d-md-block d-flex">
            <div class="col-md-6 float-left py-2">
                <div class="border">
                    1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 float-right py-2">
                <div class="border taller">
                    2 FILM POSTER
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 float-left py-2">
                <div class="border taller">
                    3 FILM META AND CONTENT
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 float-left py-2">
                <div class="border">
                    4
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/WnnCXNckAy

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the same html then you can you flex as display to parent and then set the order of the children. Setting the **order** in specific breakpoint using media queries should do the work.